# A non-normal variety that is regular in codimension one

Tags: algebraic-geometry

So, for a projective variety $X$ over, say, an algebraically closed field $\Bbbk$, being normal implies being regular in codimension one. However, the converse is not true, in addition you require an extension property. I am looking for an example of an $X$ which is regular in codimension one, but not normal.

By common lore, this can not be a curve or a surface in $\Bbb P^3$. I was hoping that maybe there is an example of a surface in $\Bbb P^4$. Beating around the bush less: I would like a small and explicit example if possible.

Comment: Basically your are searching for an isolated surface singularity, which is not normal. This has been answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143954/isolated-non-normal-surface-singularity

Comment: If you dont wanna look at the proof in the answer and prove it yourself, I can give you only the example: $k[u,v,w,z]/(w^3-z^2,u^2w-v^2,vw-uz)$.

Comment: @MooS: Very nice, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. To be honest, I haven't done much though. I have only given a reference to an older question.

Comment: ... which I did not find ;)